# token_get_all() function not working properly

Tags: php, tokenize

I want to count the curly brackets in a PHP source code, so i can eventually find the end of a method/function in the given source code.

I was adviced to use the `token_get_all()` function for this job. But for some reason it isn't splitting the given source into tokens.

I'm using the following code to test it:

```
<?php
$str = 'class someClass{
    public $var1;
    private $var2 = null;

    public function func1 ( $someVar )
    {
        echo $someVar;
    }

    public function func2 ( )
    {
        return false;
    }
}';

$bla = token_get_all ( $str );

echo '<pre>';
print_r ( $bla );
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

But this results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 311
    [1] => class someClass{
    public $var1;
    private $var2 = null;

    public function func1 ( $someVar )
    {
        echo $someVar;
    }

    public function func2 ( )
    {
        return false;
    }
}
    [2] => 1
)
```

So right now i'm kinda stuck with this. Why doesn't the `token_get_all()` tokenize the given source code..?

Comment: Don't count the closing curly brackets, as they mark the end of other blocks, not only functions' ones. Look for the `T_FUNCTION` token ;-) In case you're interested in other tokens too [here is the list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) with all the tokens the tokenizer recognizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the parser starts in HTML context (just like PHP itself), so the entire string you have passed to `token_get_all` is actually a single HTML token. You need to add `<?php` at the start of your `$str`.